# How to get access_token in contentful?

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I don't know how to get the access token in contentful. I've tried a lot of searching, copy/pasting various "solutions" but none of them working for me.
Please help me into this.

Answer (score 5):

There are two types of access tokens in Contentful. Management tokens and delivery tokens.

The delivery tokens can be found and created in the web app at https://app.contentful.com Just click the **APIs** tab in the top.

The management token needs to be created through an oauth application. You can actually do it at the contentful documentation website: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/authentication/#the-management-api

Comment: More generally: you "get" it from Contentful itself. It's not generated by code -- you get it through the Contentful admin app, as Rob states above. I just don't want you to keep trying to do this through code.

Comment: Here's a deep link which will take you to the API Keys settings page of the most recent space you've visited in Contentful: https://app.contentful.com/deeplink?link=api